# Minecraft ore generation formulas

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is there a formulas for ore generation?
I can't find it. Of course, I understand that lapis lazuli is generated according to the normal distribution law, but what about the other ores?

Comment: There are... and they are probably too complex for a simple Q&A site answer. The entire Minecraft world generation is immensely complex, and while the part of it  concerning individual ore veins isn't as complex, it's built on top of, and influenced by the massively complex underlying algorithm. For a car analogy, locating wheels of a car is pretty easy if you see the car. But trying to determine global GPS coordinates of each wheel is near-impossible if all you know about the current car location is the list of distances and turn angles from the starting point.

Comment: What can be reasonably done though is probabilistic approach - average altitude-biome-density correlations of ore locations. There is also some work regarding relative positions of generation of veins ("knowing position of 3 wheels, you can determine the 4th") - for example, method of finding diamond ores in relation to generation of clay patches in the swamp.